# data between two specific times in mysql get error

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, between

I am trying to select all data from my table where condition is

performDate will be between today 2.00 AM to tomorrow 2.00 AM

My query gives this error

```
 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

My query is

```
    SELECT * FROM `admin_marker` WHERE   
    FROM_UNIXTIME(performDate)
 BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '02:00'
                AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()+1), 0) + '02:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` expects only 2 parameters. You call it with 3 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do it that way ?

```
WHERE performdate >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 02:00:00') AND performdate <=  DATE_FORMAT(CURRENTDATE + INTERVAL +1 DAY '%Y-%m-%d 02:00:00')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `admin_marker` WHERE performdate >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 02:00:00') AND performdate <=  DATE_FORMAT(CURRENTDATE + INTERVAL +1 DAY '%Y-%m-%d 02:00:00')


#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'